# Best way to deal with building full of shulkers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I finally defeated the Ender Dragon, and went looking for End Cities.  I found one, and entered the building at the bottom of the city.  There were two shulkers at the bottom and I destroyed them, and traveled upwards and there was at least 3 shulkers all shooting at me.  I used my shield but it's nearly impossible to avoid those stupid things they shoot, half the time they hit me from behind.  I ended up floating to the top of the building and was trying to land on a balcony, but when I got there I was hit by another shulker shot and died.  I really need to get that stuff back.

What's the best way to deal with a building full of shulkers?  I need to kill them and get my stuff.  Keep in mind, I haven't found Nether Wart yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Shulker bullets can be destroyed by hitting them with any item or shooting them with an arrow, not only with a shield.
If you miss them and get hit, your best bet is to wear armor with Projectile Protection, or generic Protection, to reduce damage.

It's better to kill them all around to be safe, bring a good bow and shoot an arrow when they open. There are several Shulkers hidden outside of buildings, too. Just remember to never stand in the open air, always keep a block above you (and behind you).

And always bring a water bucket with you, to avoid fall damage.
Drinking Milk can also remove the Levitation status.

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Levitation):

> Levitation has no effect on players riding entities. It also has no effect on entities that are in water.

So you could avoid flying away using a water column, if you manage to place a water source on the roof or wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bucket of milk, chorus fruit, ender pearls and as a cheeky way to do it, anti-levitation hacks.

(I do not mean that you should hack, hacking is bad)

Shulkers teleport sometimes when they are low on health, often times it's on top of the building. Having a fire aspect sword will only make things worse, since they continue taking damage.

For the giant tower full of shulkers I recommend damaging the ones highest with a bow and working your way down.

If you really don't want to deal with them, take off all your armour and drink invisibility. Then just explore as usual, however having health potions is recommended since you won't have armour

Comment: thanks, those are some useful tips.  I am confused by what u mean by the fire aspect swords, do you mean it will make it worse *for the shulkers?*

Comment: I mean that fire aspect swords will increase the chance that they teleport. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Shulkers don't burn

Comment: @IceFreez3r the game still thinks they take fire damage, and the code that makes shulkers tp doesnt counter that

Comment: Quickly tested using carpet mods `/tick` function and a wooden sword with Fire Aspect II. The shulkers `Fire` tick is set to 160 in the tick I hit it. In the next tick it's set back to -1. They don't burn or take damage from the enchantment